# GLES 2 Android Emulator

Tags: android, error-handling, android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

I keep on getting this error when trying to run an OpenGLES 2 application on the emulator it is running 4.0.3 with gpu emulation enabled:

> Failed to create Context 0x3005 emulator: WARNING: Could not
>   initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer. could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>   could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
>   could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get
>   wglGetExtensionsStringARB could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB

:
I tried to find a suitable driver thinking that would solve the solution however that didn't work.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running with the latest ADT? The emulation support for GLES2 has been added only very recently.

Comment: In most cases the standard Android Virtual Device will not run AndEngine GLES2.0. Try testing your application on a real device and you should find it works properly. See: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: i have the same problem, since an update of the adt i cant start any emulator because of this error... do you have found any solution yet? It seems that some workarounds i found does not work for me...

Answer (score 2):

is the "Force gpu rendering" enabled on the device?

i mean the option in Settings => developer setting => force gpu rendering

Comment: where is setting option in ecllipse??

Comment: @NAVdroid - It's not in eclipse, but in the AVD Manager. Select your AVD, choose `Edit...`, and under the hardware section add new Property `GPU emulation = yes`.