# AVD or SDK (Android Emulator,)

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have windows7 64-bit, Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (JUNO ) for Windows 64 bit, and the updated and installed Android SDK for windows.

After installing the Eclipse and download through the help tab the needed android developer tool, I've unzippe the Android SDK for Windows, opened the SDK manager and installed:

1. Android SDK tool.
2. Android SDK platform tools
3. Android 2.2 (API 8) - all the folder
4. All the Extra folder.

After that I've opened the AVD manager and created a new AVD with the API 8 on with Nexus 7 (I've tried all of them ).
When I'm trying to start the AVD through the AVD manager this is what i get:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'droidX'
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

And I get the same in Eclipse of course.
I couldn't find an answer to that. I even tried to download every update Windows have because I read it helped someone.

Answer (score 0):

please use API 15 or greater.and do not use VM.

see this link :

[How do I run the Android Emulator after a Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576996/how-do-i-run-the-android-emulator-after-a-build)

also this :

[GLES 2 Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372734/gles-2-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow: 
 1. Create virtual device.
 2. Select phone catagory.
 3. Choose nexus s and press next. 
 4. choose api level 21 and abi - armeabi-v7a android 5.0.1 and press next.
 5. Uncheck use host GPU and click finish.

Set default RAM size and other details.

This worked for me.